# How to add gear icon (settings) to video.js player

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, video.js

I'm working on an old vue2 project that uses video.js (v5 or v6 not really sure). the player works, but the gear icon for settings is missing from the control bar. i believe the settings icon would enable me choose between different video quality and playback rates.

this is what my component looks like below:

```
<script>
    import videojs from "video.js";
    require('videojs-contrib-hls.js'); 
    require('path/to/js/videojs-resolution-switcher.js');
    

    export default {
        props: {
            options: {
                type: Object,
                default(){
                    return {};
                }
            },
            video: {
                type: Object,
                default(){
                    return {};
                }
            },
        },

        data() {
            return {
                player: null,
            }
        },

        mounted() {

            this.player = videojs(this.$refs.videoPlayer, this.options);

            this.player.src({
                withCredentials: false,
                src: this.getVideoSrc(),
                type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
            });
        },

        beforeDestroy() {
            if(this.player) this.player.dispose();
        },

        methods: {
            getVideoSrc(){
                return this.video.path;  
            },
        },
    }
</script>

<style>
    @import '../../../path/to/css/video-js.css';
    @import '../../../path/to/css/videojs-resolution-switcher.css';
</style>
```

I tried using the plugin 'videojs-resolution-switcher' but i get an error that says 'unable to find plugin'

I'm passing the video options as a prop from a different component and this is what it looks like below:

```
videoOptions: {
    controls: true,
    playbackRates: [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
    autoplay: false,
    responsive: true,
    preload: true,
    plugins: {
        videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
             default: 'low',
             dynamicLabel: true
        }
    }
}
```

i have tried suggestions from https://github.com/kmoskwiak/videojs-resolution-switcher/issues/74 but nothing works.

I dont know what i'm doing wrong please help me

Answer (score 0):

These are the things you should check during the integration of video.js with quality controllers. Here i have attach the code for Vue.js as well.

Resolution display in video js [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Pzd.png)

```js
//imports:
import "videojs-contrib-quality-levels"; // Import quality levels plugin
import "@mycujoo/videojs-hls-quality-selector"; // quality or resoultion menu

//Mounted time code:
    this.player = videojs(this.$refs.videoPlayer, this.options, () => {
      // Initialize the quality levels plugin
      // this.player.qualityLevels();
      this.player.log("onPlayerReady", this);
      console.log(this.player);
    });
    this.player.hlsQualitySelector({
      displayCurrentQuality: true,
    });
  },

// Option variable
{
        autoplay: true,
        controls: true,
        responsive: true,
        preload: true,
        playbackRates: [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
        html5: {
          hls: {
            // withCredentials: true,
            overrideNative: true,
          },
        },
        sources: [
          {
            // withCredentials: true,
            src: `test.m3u8`,
            type: "application/x-mpegURL",
          },
        ],
        plugins: {
          qualityLevels: {},
        },
      }
```